# PHP empty $_POST and $_FILES with large file upload

Tags: php, large-file-upload

Please do **not** close this as a duplicate. I know there are many similar questions posted here, but I have tried *all* of those answers with no change in the problem. I've looked into this for more than a week. All the answers I have found talk about the settings below, which I have already set properly.

My MAMP server's php.ini includes the following:

```
    file_uploads         On
    upload_max_filesize  16700000
    post_max_size        16777216
    memory_limit         768M
    max_input_time       360
    max_execution_time   360
```

My .htaccess file repeats these:

```
    php_value file_uploads         On
    php_value upload_max_filesize  16700000
    php_value post_max_size        16777216
    php_value memory_limit         768M
    php_value max_input_time       360
    php_value max_execution_time   360
```

and also has:

```
LimitRequestBody 16777216 
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRequestBodyLimit        16777216
    SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 16777216
</IfModule>
```

My httd.conf file includes the same settings.

When I examine at runtime with `ini_get()`, I see the php ini values given above, except that `max_execution_time` is always 0 (unlimited), regardless of these settings.

Using `FormData` in a `XMLHttpRequest`, if I upload a file up to about 1meg in size, the Content-length header looks correct and everything works fine. If I upload a file even slightly larger, I see all the same values, the Content-length header looks correct (and way less than `post_max_size`), but `$_POST` and `$_FILES` are empty, and the client sees HTTP status `413 Request Entity Too Large`. Both the php and apache logs files show no errors.

UPDATE:

On further investigation I find `Requested content-length of 1829686 is larger than the configured limit of 1024000` in `apache_ssl_request.log`. So where is this limit of 1024000 coming from? What limit is this? `find /Applications/MAMP -type f -exec grep -l 1024000 '{}' \;` only finds this error message, no config file entries with this value.

Comment: Check httpd logs/config

Comment: No error messages logged. Config file as described in original post.

Comment: **httpd** config. Not PHP

Comment: I have ```LimitRequestBody 16777216``` there and in my .htaccess file. What other settings do you have in mind?

Comment: How do I get this not to be marked as a duplicate since the answers given to the seeming dupes have been accounted for here and have not resolved this problem?

Comment: people with sufficient [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) can vote to re-open your question if they deem it appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for that info. I can only hope!

Comment: `does not work` do not provide any additional information, if you ask me.

Comment: `Both the php and apache logs files show no errors` what about enforcing logging? both apache and php have such features

Comment: On further investigation I find ```Requested content-length of 1829
686 is larger than the configured limit of 1024000``` in ```apache_ssl_request.log```. So where is this limit of 1024000 coming from? What limit is this? ```find /Applications/MAMP -type f -exec grep -l 1024000 '{}' \;``` only finds this error message, no config file entries with this value.

Comment: Solved. Super-embarrassing, stupid error.

My .htaccess includes a long list of known-evil IP addresses, making it a bit long. In all the times I checked my file upload settings near the top of this file, I never noticed that I had a very small setting for one of the factors already sitting at the end of .htaccess, overwriting the correct value I had at the top.

Why am I admitting this? To offer the following general advice:

If you are sure you are making a correct setting and it seems to be overwritten, look lower down in the same file(s) in which you have made the correct setting.